# Displaying data into HTML Tables

Tags: html, css

I am able to display my data from db. I want to display in a table under tabs but then my data appears crooked. The rows are not straight. why is that happening to the table?

it is arranged kind of this way.

the updated code below doesn't provide the right format for the table 
**Table**

```
  id  name
     1    James
    4   Michel
   2  Jonathan
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">

        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <li><a href="#tab_{{ $item->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$item->name!!}</a></li>
                @endforeach             
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_{{ $item->id }}">
                        @foreach($item->products as $product)
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th>No#</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$product->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        @endforeach         
                    </div>    
                @endforeach         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Updated Code

**Update**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">

        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <li><a href="#tab_{{ $item->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$item->name!!}</a></li>
                @endforeach             
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_{{ $item->id }}">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <th>No#</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>
                        @foreach($item->products as $product)

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$product->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                        @endforeach         

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>    
                @endforeach         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's your final HTML output?

Comment: This ain't only HTML. The foreach is from a framework language. What framework do you use? And what Quentin says is the awnser

Comment: In your code 'th' number 3 but under tbody I can see only 2 'td', is this a cause?

Answer (score 1):

The start of your `foreach products` is before the `<table>` start tag.

You are, however, trying to generate *one row per product*, so it should be immediately before the `<tr>` start tag.

The matching `endforeach` should likewise be moved to just after the `</tr>` end tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `@foreach()` + corresponding `@endforeach` **inside** the `<tbody>`, otherwise you are outputting a new table for each product. This is how it should be:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>No#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($item->products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->id   }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what about the `@foreach()` for the tab-content . this line ` <div class="tab-content">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_{{ $item->id }}">`

Comment: do i have to maintain it?

Comment: You'll probably need to keep it as it generates the tabs, each of which contains a table of products.

Comment: Looks good to me, but it is up to you to decide if it does what you want.